# looking to lookup a value of variable row/column in different worksheet

Tags: excel

I was wondering if there was a way to perform the following operation in excel:

1. *In sheet1 I have 2 columns, ColA is the variable name and ColB looks up a value attributed to that variable in sheet2*
2. *In sheet2, the `variable name` in Sheet1ColA is found along Row5, the Col# will vary as sheet2 is updated in the future*
3. *The value I'm looking to pickup from sheet2 has a fixed name, not present in sheet1, but again, its Row# will vary as sheet2 grows. This is normally a simply fix by using `vlookup("fixed name", ...)`, but vlookup isn't sufficient for the second criteria*

My excel knowledge doesn't get far past sumifs, vlookups and pivottables; so perhaps there is a command I'm unfamiliar with?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: After finding the column number in #2, how do you use that to locate #3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a 2-dimensional lookup - if so you can do this using
=INDEX(Sheet2Table,Match(sheet1variablename,sheet2row5,0),Match(FixedName,RangecontainingFixedNames,0))

More examples for this and also 3-dimensional lookup and wild-card lookup can be found at my [optimising lookups page](http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeede.htm)

Comment: Thanks Charles that's perfect